# Can you take a feat that you can not use at the current level if there are no prerequisites?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, metamagic, character-levels

Quicken spell feat doesn't have any prerequisites to take. Can I take it at an earlier level than I can use it and have it for when I can?